# Google OAuth Issue

Tags: umbraco, oauth2-playground

I have a Umbraco website that has google sign in button configured as follows:

At the top of the page (inside the header section) I have the scripts for calling google API:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" async defer></script>
<script>
        function start() {
          gapi.load('auth2', function() {
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
              client_id: '<myapp client Id>.apps.googleusercontent.com',
              // Scopes to request in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
              redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:40136/umbraco/Surface/AuthSurface/GoogleAuthrizedUser',
              scope: 'profile email'
            });
          });
        } 
 </script>
```

In the body section of the code I have the google button setup and associated click function:

```
<script>
 function onSignIn(authResult) {
    if (authResult['code']) {
      var authCode = authResult['code'];
      console.log("Authorization Code: " + authCode);
      $.post("/umbraco/Surface/AuthSurface/GoogleAuthrizedUser", { code: authCode })
        .done(function(msg) {
            // Success settings
         })
        .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {

        });
    } else {
       //authResult['code'] is null
       //handle the error message.
    }
  };
 </script>
```

Controller code that handles the call back on the server end:

```
  public class AuthSurfaceController : SurfaceController
  {
       public ActionResult GoogleAuthrizedUser()
      {
        string AuthCode = HttpContext.Request["code"];
        var info = new GoogleAccessTokenResponse();
        var client = new GoogleOAuthClient();
        try
        {
          info = client.GetAccessTokenFromAuthorizationCode(AuthCode);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          var strMessage = String.Format("<div class=\"info\"><p>{0}</p><p>{1}</p></div>", "Google Login Error",
          ex.Message);
         return Json(new AjaxOperationResponse(false, strMessage));
        }
     }
 }
```

On the Serverside I am using Skybrud Social plugin for accessing google apis.

The google authentication happens in the popup and authorizes client with credentials and  *authResult['code']* has a valid code.

In the controller when I initialize the client and call the function *GetAccessTokenFromAuthorizationCode(AuthCode)*, it returns an exception of 'Invalid Request'

I tried checking this *authResult['code']* returned in the javascript function onSignIn in the https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Same error description is shown 'Invalid request'. I am not sure why this is happening. The error returned is "invalid_grant"

Can anyone have a solution to this problem?  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In your surface controller you're initializing a new instance of `GoogleOAuthClient`, but without setting any of the properties. The `GetAccessTokenFromAuthorizationCode` method requires the `ClientId`, `ClientSecret` and `RedirectUri` properties to have a value. You can initialize the properties like this:

```
// Initialize a new instance of the OAuth client
GoogleOAuthClient oauth = new GoogleOAuthClient {
    ClientId = "The client ID of your project",
    ClientSecret = "The client secret of your project",
    RedirectUri = "The return URI (where users should be redirected after the login)"
};
```

You can read more about authentication in the documentation: http://social.skybrud.dk/google/authentication/ (the approach explained there will however not use any JavaScript)

Comment: @abjemer:  I have tried that approach. Have initialized the 'GoogleOAuthClient' with 'ClientId', 'ClientSecret' and 'RedirectUri' before calling on 'GetAccessTokenFromAuthrizationCode' method.

Comment: @abjemer:  I have tried that approach. Have initialized the 'GoogleOAuthClient' with 'ClientId', 'ClientSecret' and ' RedirectUri ' before calling on 'GetAccessTokenFromAuthrizationCode' method.  But takes away the asynchronous call back from javascript which handles the pop-up for authentication, authorization but gives offline scope access and comes back  with authResult['code'] as explained in my query above.  Would like to use approach that is explained here  https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow.  Not wishing to use Response.Redirect(authorizationUrl)

Comment: @abjemer our website google authentication and authorization is happening from the menu popup. Hence redirecting away to a different page will loose the smooth user experience that asynchronous javascript brings for login workflow.